# how to stop user to download the current app

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app on the app store with version as 1.5

I update it to 1.6 and have some problems. The app with 1.6 is live.

What I want to do is revert app store to 1.5 and let users not to download 1.6

OR

Don't let user download 1.6 and I will fix those issue and update to 1.7 and I will allow user to download 1.7

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store functionality and support, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be working solution for now

1.Go to your App Summary Page.

2.Click on Rights and Pricing button.

[image]

3.Click on specific territories.

[image]

4.Deselect all the stores and then save changes.

Comment: but this will not show 1.5 version... right? also app will not be on app store... right?

Comment: Yeah.. I don't know if there is a way to do so.

Comment: There is no way to revered back to a previous version. You best option is to remove it from sale for now by remove the specific territories just as Inder posted.

Comment: @FahimParkar, you probably cannot show the previously submitted `1.5` again in AppStore as `1.5` (there is no downgrade support in AppStore), maybe you can upload a new version which is identical to `1.5`, and you can put it under version `1.6.1` or something.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore : [could you please take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363867/iphone-6-plus-giving-same-output-even-data-is-updated)

Answer (score -1):

I know no way of downgrade on this Apple Store. But if you found you bug and fixed it, you can ask for an expedited review one your fixed version is uploaded :

Go to iTunes connect -> select your app -> select the fixed version "Waiting for review" -> Contact us.

[image]

I used this once for an critical bug and the review was done within 24 hours. You should notice that it's up to Apple to decide if they will do a expedited review or not.